# How can a non-soldier Shepard defeat the Harbinger on the Collector ship quickly?

Tags: mass-effect-2

In Mass Effect 2, there is a section where you are ambushed while on a floating platform within a Collector ship. While here, several waves of enemies engage you from a few sides starting on nearby platforms that attach to yours. Harbinger frequently "assumes direct control" of Collectors during these fights. The most troubling of these waves is probably the first one because Harbinger starts out very close to your team and you have basically no options to retreat. Thus, the only high-level strategy I can think of is to destroy Harbinger before he closes on my team.

On a difficulty other than the highest (Insanity, I think it is called) destroying him isn't a big deal for any class. However, I really only enjoy ME2 on Insanity.  As a soldier, selecting the upgraded assault rifle for your upgrade enables you to do sufficient damage to Harbinger that you can put him down before he reaches you. However, I haven't found a way for any other class to deal enough damage to Harbinger in that short space of time.  (This is the only part of the game where I have to tone the difficulty down for other classes.)

Assuming Insanity difficulty, and whatever party/armor/weapon* combination you'd like, how can a non-soldier Shepard and friends defeat Harbinger at this point in the game.

*While I own most of the DLC, I do not own any DLC that only grants weapon packs as they seem to be strictly better than the in-game weapons, and thus I consider using such DLC to be paying money to lower the difficulty (cheating.)

Comment: Ignore/avoid the Direct Controlled drone as much as possible, kill off his respawn fodder before taking him out.

Comment: It's been a long time since I played Mass Effect 2, but IIRC Harbringer has a shield. Make sure to have someone in your party who has powers that are strong against his shield type, and use them (or use your own powers if applicable).

Comment: The direct controlled drone is too dangerous to ignore at the start of that fight as he is too close to my group.  The respawns aren't as bad because they'll be further back.  On Insanity, he has barriers as well as armor, no shields.

Comment: It's been awhile but I always play the steathier style.  Infiltrator.  I max out sniper rifles and I have tactical cloak.  Usually in two to three hits with the Black Widow (if I remember correctly)

Comment: Any "viable" party should consist of a combination of powers that can dispatch the enemies that you yourself cannot effectively deal with. If you have problems with the harbinger, you should bring someone that can combo powers to effectively break barrier and armor. If I recall correctly, any combination of Concussive Shot, Warp, Ignite or Reave(?) should work. While I mostly played as a soldier, the only companions I ever used for extended time were Liara and EDI because they fit that bill perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

With a well-built Infiltrator, Harbinger dies in two headshots from the Widow. One if you get a squadmate to use max Warp first.